# Why sinatra is a DSL?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

The very [first line](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra#sinatra) written about `sinatra` is *it is DSL for quickly creating web applications in Ruby with minimal effort*. I can understand it is light weight, very flexible, quick for creating web apps and with minimal effort but not able to understand how it is a DSL?

Comment: I think, strictly speaking, Sinatra isn't a *language* but more like a *library* and a defined set of programming patterns that uses the Ruby language. But in a Ruby based framework, one can create specific, higher level programming patterns that aid in writing for a specific domain. So perhaps calling the library (or the set of patterns) a "language" is appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

One reason is that it defines actions ("verbs") within its domain as methods, for example:

```
get '/hi' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

Here Sinatra has incorporated an action from its domain--namely the HTTP request method "GET"--into its "vocabulary."

(Similar to building a library around banking and defining methods like `account` or `customer`.)

Is this more about the true definition of [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)?